# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la suma de los datos seleccionados de una columna de un DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Quisiera algo de ayuda con esto: Tengo unos datos en un DataGridView, quiero que el usuario pueda seleccionar a su antojo las filas que desee y que el programa lea los datos de esa selección correspondientes a la columna Subtotal y muestre la sumatoria.

[image: Texto]

Estoy desarrollando en **Visual Studio 2019 / WinForms / C#**

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a revisar [ask]. Has intentado algo?

Comment: Si, intenté algunos ForEach... nada que realmente funcione.

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que has intentado para que recibas ayuda basado en lo que tienes pensado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he logrado resolverlo. Les comparto el código comentado para quien desee implementar esto mismo en sus programas (dgREGISTROS es el DataGridView):

```
// OBTENGO EL NÚMERO DE FILAS SELECCIONADAS
int CantFilas = dgREGISTROS.SelectedRows.Count;

//CREO UN ARRAY CUYA DIMENSIÓN SERÁ EL NÚMERO DE FILAS SELECCIONADAS
//EN ESTE ARRAY SE ALMACENARÁN LOS INDICES DE LAS FILAS SELECCIONADAS
int[] Indices = new int[CantFilas];

//UN CONTADOR PARA IR LLENANDO EL ARRAY
int Contador = 0;

//VARIABLE QUE GUARDARÁ LA SUMATORIA
double SumSubT = 0;

//RECORRO TODAS LAS FILAS SELECCIONADAS
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgREGISTROS.SelectedRows)
{               
    //ASIGNO A CADA ELEMENTO DEL ARRAY EL VALOR DEL INDICE DE CADA FILA
    Indices[Contador] = row.Index;       

    //SUMO 1 A CONTADOR PARA EL SIGUIENTE            
    Contador++;               
}

//CONOCIENDO LOS INDICES DE LAS FILAS SELECCIONADAS ESPECIFICO LA COLUMNA Y SUMO SUS VALORES
for (int i = 0; i < CantFilas; i++)
{
    SumSubT += double.Parse(dgREGISTROS.Rows[Indices[i]].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
}
```